# Restart Kubernetes on Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I have configured one Ubuntu system (192.168.1.2) to be a master and minion.

Another Ubuntu machine to be a minion (192.168.1.3). I performed upgrade on Ubuntu machine that was both master and minion and rebooted the system.

Now when I perform:

`kubectl get nodes`

The node (192.168.1.2) is down.

I went through the documentation but could not find any documentation that explains how to add back the lost nodes.

I need some help to understand how to bring the node back into the Kubernetes cluster. Is there any script to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any script, but here are a few basic things might help:

1. Please ensure that `kubelet` and `docker` services are running on the node in question.
2. Run `kubectl describe node <nodename>` to get additional details.
3. Get the logs of `kubelet` service if it is already running by executing `journalctl -u kubelet`